# SimpleTesting-PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: drupal-7, simpletest

SimpleTesting-PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02] View Edit Revisions Posted by ichionid on December 15, 2011 at 10:56am Hi all,

I am in the processes of developing a module. I am trying to incorporate SimpleTest module in order to have a separate place that contains my code tests.

However, when I try to run a query against the tables in the database, which are build by me, I get:
**PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'playground.simpletest311135TABLENAME**

It tries to find a table simpletest311135TABLENAME while it should look for TABLENAME. It always adds simpletest and some random number.

When I run queries against drupal default tables, like users and sessions, everything works perfect. Any workaround?

Giannis

---

The  actual function is

```
function dlm_job_finished($jobId,$urls,$messageFromFS){
    $query    =  db_select('users','u');
    $query    -> fields('u',array('uid'));
    $d_alias  =  $query->innerJoin('dlm_user_auth_entities','d','%alias.uid = u.uid');
    $query    -> condition("{$d_alias}.jid",$jobId);
    $result   =  $query->execute();
    $message = variable_get('dlm_settings_email_message').'<br />';
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      foreach ($urls as $file_url_to_download){
        $message.= '<a href="'.$file_url_to_download.'">'.$file_url_to_download.'</a> <br /> ';
      }
      $message.=$messageFromFS.'<br />';      
      dlm_mail_notifier($record->uid,$message);
    }
  }
```

the test function is :

```
class DlmTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase{

  public function setUp(){
    parent::setUp('dlm');
  }

    public function testDlmJobFinished(){
        $info = module_invoke(
                  'dlm',
                  'job_finished',
                  'awsedrfvcxzsdfrtawsedrfvcxzsdfrt',
                  array(
                    'http://media.holkeydonkey.com/download/frehvf64fdsffdf.zip',
                    'http://media.marioBos.com/download/12.zip',
                  ),
                  "additional message!"
                );
      }
}
```

Inside the test class the only functions that I made work is the ones that query the default drupal database tables. Also, the function above is working, I invoked in a different way and it worked, the problem is that I cannot get it working with Drupal's simpletesting module.

Comment: Can you post the specific lines of code that are causing this error?

Comment: please see the edited version above!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misunderstood but I think you're trying to run a query with a simple inner join? If so your syntax is wrong, it should look like this:

```
$query = db_select('users','u')
  ->fields('u',array('uid'))
  ->condition('d.jid', $jobId);

$query->innerJoin('dlm_user_auth_entities', 'd', 'd.uid = u.uid');

$results = $query->execute();
```

The problem is with your condition:

```
`$query -> condition("{$d_alias}.jid",$jobId);`
```

The variable assigned to `$d_alias` (which you are using as your alias name in the above condition) is returned from `$query->innerJoin()` which doesn't return a string representation of the alias, it returns an object. The table name you're getting in your query might be the string representation of that object (`simpletest311135`).

When you use the second argument of `innerJoin()` that becomes the alias that the joined table will be known by in the rest of your query. So you can just use `->condition('d.jid', $jobId)` as in the example above.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks you for the hint ;) I cannot find the reference for using the alias the way I did, but I'll provide it when able too! Unfortunately still I get the same response. I'll get back if I find an answer or if you have any suggestions more your welcome!